# How to set a default List for @Value in SpringBoot ApiSettings

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and I am trying to read some properties from api.properties. I am getting & setting them from ApiSettings class. But I would like to add a default List is someone using my API doesn't define this property. Please let me know how to set a default list using @value in my ApiSettings class

```
@Value("ACCEPTED,DONE,RESOLVED,CLOSED")
private List<String> validStoryStatus;
```

The above one that I have listed is wrongly formatted, what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the key and the default values separated by colon and use split function to cast it to list

```
@Value("#{'${your.key:ACCEPTED,DONE,RESOLVED,CLOSED}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> validStoryStatus;
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I try to read this property I am getting the whole thing as a single value. Not as a list :-|

Comment: if I am reading from properties file (validStoryStatus=ACCEPTED,DONE,RESOLVED,CLOSED) , I get this as a list. If I comment this line and get the default from @Value, I get it as a String Value

Comment: You can use split function to cast it to list, see the edit

Answer (score 0):

You might find it a little cleaner to just use a `String[]`

```
@Value("${valid-story-status:ACCEPTED, DONE, RESOLVED, CLOSED}")
private String[] validStoryStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
@Value("${exclude.patterns:/misc/ping,/actuator/health,/actuator/prometheus}")
private List<String> excludePatterns;
```

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is :

```
@Value("#{'${onekey:ACCEPTED,DONE,RESOLVED,CLOSED}'.split(',')}")   
private List<String> validStoryStatus;
```